# Using textbox background color and content as program status indicator

Tags: android, android-layout, visibility

I would like to create an indicator that would clearly show the user whether a certain feature of my application is "ON" or "OFF". Ideally a textbox with white font and black background saying "OFF", that would change to having a green background and black font saying "ON". What is the best way to implement this? 
XML code might be something like this,

```
<LinearLayout
     android:orientation="horizontal"
     android:layout_width="match_parent" 
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:gravity="right">
 <TextView
    style="@style/colorSizeStylexml"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginLeft="10dip"
    android:text="Tracklog: " />

     <TextView
         android:id="@+id/textView"
         android:layout_width="40dp"
         android:layout_height="40dp"
         android:gravity="center"
         android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
         android:layout_marginRight="10dip"
         android:text="ON"
         android:background="#ff58ff2d"
         android:textStyle="bold" />
 </LinearLayout>
```

With a layout something like this,

[image]

While I can imagine doing the layout and conditionals mostly in JAVA, I suspect that keeping as much of the layout as possible in XML is preferred.
What is the best way to go about this? TIA

**Update**
Here's the answer as implemented,

```
public void setTracklogOnOffIndicator(View v){
    tvOn = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.textViewOn);
    tvOff = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.textViewOff);

    if(MainActivity.iTrackLogFlag == 0) {//tracklog is OFF
        tvOff.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        tvOn.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    }else if((MainActivity.iTrackLogFlag == 1)){//tracklog is ON
        tvOff.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        tvOn.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    }
}
```

...and the XML,

```
     <TextView
         android:id="@+id/textViewOff"
         android:layout_width="40dp"
         android:layout_height="40dp"
         android:gravity="center"
         android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
         android:layout_marginRight="10dip"
         android:text="OFF"
         android:background="#ff000000"
         android:textStyle="bold"
         android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
         android:textColor="#ffffffff" />
     <TextView
         android:id="@+id/textViewOn"
         android:layout_width="40dp"
         android:layout_height="40dp"
         android:gravity="center"
         android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
         android:layout_marginRight="10dip"
         android:text="ON"
         android:background="#ff58ff2d"
         android:textStyle="bold" />
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could define two TextViews, one for each state and then flip visibility in your code.

```
onTextView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
offTextView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
```

or vice versa.